# 2007 Hyundai Santa Fe, I am squirting power steering fluid out from a boot connecting to passenger front tire. What is going on?

Tags: steering, power

The power steering fluid is constantly running out thru a hole in what looks like to be a boot on passenger front tire. Causing steering wheel to be jerky and power steering pump to scream.

Answer (score 2):

That is likely to be the steering rack boot or bellows and it will need replacing, ideally before you drive it again.

You could possibly get away with topping up the fluid and driving it straight to the shop to get the work done as long as they are close - less than 5 miles.